# feedback feature in ios using google spreadsheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, google-api-objc-client

I want to implement the user feedback feature in ios application.

I am thinking of integrating the google ios api in the ios app.

I want to add the user feedback in the developers google spreadsheet.

Any user who writes feedback and sends bugs,screenshots will be added to spreadsheet on the google drive of the developer.

Anybody has attempted this feature? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I think this question is to broad asking for suggestions on how to do something is really open.  Please show us what you have done and what issues you are having with it.

Comment: @DaImTo, I tried google sample code, it worked for the google docs. But no idea about the google spreadsheet

Comment: https://github.com/googledrive/ios-quickeditor

Comment: Google sheets is a different api, and its really old I am not sure you will find a tutorial for it for Ios.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am testing this old API. Is it compatible with the latest ios9.2 ?

Comment: Note a clue. Its a gdata api which returns xml I cant be of much help with ios sorry.  see if you can find an old gdata ios client library if your lucky it will still work.

Comment: @DaImTo Great. Thank you. I will see this one.